# About Readers/writers synchronization

Tags: c, synchronization, mutex, semaphore

i'm looking at a readers/writers syncronization implementation and i have a question.

This is the code i'm looking at:

```
start_reading(){
lock(m);
if (em_escrita || escritores_espera > 0) {
    leitores_espera++;
    unlock(m);
    wait(readers);
    lock(m);
}else
    nleitores++;
unlock(m);
}

finish_reading(){
lock(m);
nleitores--;
if (nleitores == 0 && escritores_espera > 0){
    post(writers);
    em_escrita=TRUE;
    escritores_espera--;
}
unlock(m);
}
```

This is the reader code, my question is, why do the wait(readers) is done outside the mutual exclusion area. And by the same reasons why isn't the Post(writers) done outside too ?

This code is from the operational systems course so i'm pretty sure it is correct.

Can somebody tell me the difference ?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Please indent your code properly, give us a hint on your OS and also give us the declarations of your global functions and variables.

Answer (score 0):

In any case the waiting with locked resource is the bad idea. If resource can be released while waiting then it should be released (to prevent locking another one who like to lock the resource).

Semaphore post don't lock any resources and may be used in any context (not paying attention to the locking).